# How to place mask behavior in primeng p-calendar?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

In p-calendar I'm not able to put masking behaviour.
Example: If user enters 08262022, I want to change it to 08/26/2022.
How is it possible? Please give any suggestions